# Project management & tracking program for small team

Tags: project-management

We have a small law firm of 8 people and are looking for an easy way to manage our projects. We have trouble with keeping track of projects. For example, I created a contract for a client and handed it over for the boss to review before he sent it off to the client. Unfortunately my boss is so busy with additional projects that he forgot to review it and the project stopped there for 2 weeks. We'd like something to keep track of projects like these.

A quick Google search reveals many possibilities: Flow, Trello, Asana, Basecamp, Quire. They all look good, but we don't have the free time to experiment with every one of them as a team. Hopefully you can direct us to the top choices.

We're looking for a project management program that satisfies the following requirements:

- Is super easy for non techie people to use.
- Has a simple interface.
- Projects are visual-based and you can see them all in one dashboard.
- Projects can be handed off to another person.
- Maybe color-coded according to the urgency of the project.
- Is not more than $200 a year.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Would you consider [answering your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), with some more details included? If it's a solution you accept, it might be acceptable to others as well :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working in an IT department of 3 people, we were looking at the same stuff. We had to find something that would have an app, we aimed for free, and was easy to navigate/use, along with being able to assign quickly and easily, both on the app and desktop version.

[Asana](http://www.asana.com) met all of our requirements and the more we use it, the more we love it. There are cons to it though, and may/may not apply to you.

**Pros:**

- Easy to use;
- Cheap (we use it for free);
- Easy to create categories, then sub tasks under those categories;
- Can assign to another user in just a couple of clicks;
- Daily emails to notify us of anything coming up or past due;
- Integrates with Google Calendar, or mostly any calendar at that.

**Cons:**

- When integrating with a calendar, dates don't always transfer over properly;
- Can be confusing at first distinguishing between "Task Name" and Description, as well as comments when you first begin;
- You can't designate a time for projects to be completed, only a date.

Highly recommended, even with non-tech savvy groups.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. With your advice I narrowed Asana down to the top two contenders. The other contender is GQueues. With a few days of side by side testing complete, GQueues is winning out. It's simple, visual, uses Google Calendar seemlessly, and cheaper at only $25 a person per year.

Comment: All that matters is that you find something that works for your group. Glad I was able to be of some help though :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/). It has everything you are looking for and the interface is simple and easy to use.

You will be able to create and manage all of your projects on one or several boards, assign tasks to users and attach documents. All of this will be visually displayed on the task cards and you can add color coding and notifications to coordinate with other team members.

This is an agile project management software equipped with a variety of features, but i have found that it is done in such a way that you can truly only use what you need and forget about the rest.

Comment: Thank you, I checked out Eylean Board and it looks very powerful. It seems to be just the product I would want. The only issue is the price, since my team is skeptical about project management software to begin with, I'm unsure if I can get them to commit to a $345 a year price for a software they don't think they need.

Answer (score 0):

Update after 2 years.

I settled on [Trello](https://trello.com/) as the best project management software.

**Reasons**

- Free, at the moment we're using the free version.
- Visual, the Kanban style design allows you to see all the projects in one dashboard.
- Integrates with Google Calendar
- Project cards can be color coded to reflect the level of urgency.
- Simple to use. It is a super simple interface that any non-techie can use.