# Online platform for small business (featuring project management, calendar, contacts)

Tags: web-apps, project-management, calendar, crm

I'm helping a friend who is looking for an online platform for her small business. What she wants is something with:

- Project management for …

  - … maintainance projects
  - … one-time ("ordinary") projects
- A calendar
- Contact management

A few other people (as well as she herself) should be able to login to the system.

All these things would optimally be integrated with each other - so for example when there is a deadline for a project she could see that deadline in the calendar.

What can you recommend that we try?

Either self-hosted or hosted is fine, but preferably hosted since that will make it easier for her to use. She is willing to pay a maximum of $30/month.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Google G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/) (formerly *Google Apps for Work*) it's a competitive and versatile solution, so it should be among the first choices. It also has a small learning curve if you are a Google user (and who is not these days?), and a populated ecosystem of [business apps](https://apps.google.com/marketplace/?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it's good for her because she already has an email address with google. Do you know if G Suite includes some form of project planning software as well?

Comment: [GQueues](https://www.gqueues.com/) seems to be one way to go, it's also recommended in an answer to [this question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31343/project-management-tracking-program-for-small-team)

Comment: You are welcome. About project management [this article](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/use-at-work/project-management/) from the Google Learning Center may help too. And [here](https://apps.google.com/marketplace/search/Project%20management?hl=en) other apps in the G Suite Marketplace. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to look at [Kolab Groupware](https://kolab.org/). From this link:

> The Kolab.org Community is a Free Software initiative building a unified communication and collaboration system that you can install on your own server. If you don't want to run your own server, consider using hosted Kolab like offered by "Kolab Now".

Works great, and you only use the features you're interested in.